# Drawing buffer to D3D9 texture

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to draw CEF buffer (returned on OnPaint) to D3D9 texture of the game, and game randomly premanently freezes. I figured out that code provided below is the reason of the game freeze, but still can't understand. What did I miss?

```
// To create texture I use this code
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 tWebPNG;
D3DXCreateTexture(device, width, height, 1, D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &tWebPNG);

// And the problem in that method

    void OnPaint(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, PaintElementType type, const RectList& dirtyRects, const void* buffer, int width, int height)
    {

        D3DLOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
        D3DSURFACE_DESC SurfaceDesc;
        IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;
        tWebPNG->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pSurface);

        pSurface->GetDesc(&SurfaceDesc);
        pSurface->LockRect(&LockedRect, nullptr, 0);
        
        auto dest = (unsigned char*)LockedRect.pBits;
        auto src = (const char*)buffer;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        {
            memcpy(dest, src, width * 4);
            dest += LockedRect.Pitch;
            src += width * 4;
        }


        pSurface->UnlockRect();
    }
```

To be clear: CEF is rendered as expected, it have no errors and here is just texture render problem. Hope to get any help

After discussing in comments, I have modified my code a bit:

```cpp
// Modified OnPaint to work with mutaxes
    void OnPaint(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, PaintElementType type, const RectList& dirtyRects, const void* buffer, int width, int height)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_RenderData.dataMutex);

            // Store render data
            m_RenderData.buffer = buffer;
            m_RenderData.width = width;
            m_RenderData.height = height;
            m_RenderData.dirtyRects = dirtyRects;
            m_RenderData.changed = true;
        }

        // Wait for the main thread to handle drawing the texture
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_RenderData.cvMutex);
        m_RenderData.cv.wait(lock);
    }


// This method is intended to draw into d3d9 layer
void Browser::draw()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_RenderData.dataMutex);

    IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;

    tWebPNG->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pSurface);

    if (m_RenderData.changed)
    {
        // Lock surface
        D3DLOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
        if (FAILED(pSurface->LockRect(&LockedRect, nullptr, 0))) {
            m_RenderData.cv.notify_all();
            return;
        }

        // Update changed state
        m_RenderData.changed = false;

        D3DSURFACE_DESC SurfaceDesc;
        IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;
        tWebPNG->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pSurface);

        pSurface->GetDesc(&SurfaceDesc);
        pSurface->LockRect(&LockedRect, nullptr, 0);

        auto dest = (unsigned char*)LockedRect.pBits;
        auto src = (const char*)m_RenderData.buffer;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        {
            memcpy(dest, src, width * 4);
            dest += LockedRect.Pitch;
            src += width * 4;
        }

        // Unlock surface
        pSurface->UnlockRect();
    }

    D3DXVECTOR3* vector = new D3DXVECTOR3(0, 0, 0);

    sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
    sprite->Draw(tWebPNG, NULL, NULL, vector, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    sprite->End();
    
    m_RenderData.cv.notify_all();

}
```

Comment: Is your paint handler running on the main thread (as in the D3D thread), or a random thread pool thread from Chrome?

Comment: @Blindy hello! Thank you for reply. They're in different threads:
```[17:25:49]: 24844 - main thread
[17:25:57]: 1240 - onpaint thread
```

Comment: There's your problem, you can't do that. I even bet that you get multiple overlapping paint events on multiple threads. You need to use the paint event to copy the data to a temporary buffer, synchronized by mutexes, and have the D3D thread handle the texture transfer from that buffer, again using the mutex.

Comment: One further suggestion is to keep the stride (pitch) calculation in the event handler, and have the temporary buffer set up for a single straight `memcpy` to the locked texture for performance reasons.

Comment: @Blindy I didn't understand you a bit. What do you mean "have the D3D thread handle the texture transfer from that buffer, again using the mutex"? I should have separate thread from the main where I will draw to D3D texture?

Comment: "Main thread" means different things to different units of code. From Chrome's point of view, the main thread is different than what D3D would consider the main thread for example. So, be precise in your wording. With that in mind, what's confusing you about "D3D thread"?

Comment: @Blindy probably I figured out what did you mean. I have changed my code to make draw only on main D3D thread (the thread where device was gathered), but once I did it, the game crashes. Can you look at my code? Did I miss something again? I have added it into the question

Comment: No, I said **copy the data** not the pointer. The pointer will obviously be freed after the event, you need to make your own buffer and copy it in that buffer.

Comment: And you don't need to block Chrome until you render, keep them asynchronous.

Comment: @Blindy
I tried to make copying:
```int size = width * height * 4;

void* mybuffer = malloc(size);
memcpy(mybuffer, buffer, size);
m_RenderData.buffer = mybuffer;
```, but it still crashes. I hope I'm not looking super-stupid, I'm just a beginner 
Also I have removed lock from end of `onPaint`

Comment: Allocate the buffer only once, not every time. And use the debugger to figure out the problem, "it crashes" is meaningless.

Comment: @Blindy thank you! Can you write your suggestion as an answer? I will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed above, the paint event (and override method) are both called [on the CefBrowser UI thread](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_OnPaint.htm), and locking the same texture multiple times before it gets released will deadlock your entire D3D context.

The fix is to separate the paint event handler (which is responsible for saving the rendered Chrome image to an internal buffer) from the D3D render thread (which is responsible for uploading the internal buffer to the D3D texture and rendering with it).